# Restore jQuery-UI dialog's size and position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I save a jQuery dialog's position and size on each move/resize in localStore:

```
//saving dialog's position and size
$(".dialog").on("dialogdragstop dialogresizestop", function() {
  var $dialog = $(this);
  var dialogName = $dialog.dialog("option", "title");
  var storageName = "DialogSettings-" + dialogName;
  var position = $dialog.dialog("option", "position");

  var settings = {};
  settings.width = $dialog.dialog("option", "width");
  settings.height = $dialog.dialog("option", "height");
  settings.position = position.at;
  var jsonSettings = JSON.stringify(settings);
  localStorage[storageName] = JSON.stringify(settings);
});
```

And I restore position and size with this function on side reload:

```
function restoreDialogSettings() {
  $(".dialog").each(function() {
    var $dialog = $(this);
    var dialogName = $dialog.dialog("option", "title");
    var storageName = "DialogSettings-" + dialogName;

    if (localStorage[storageName]) {
      var settings = JSON.parse(localStorage[storageName]);

      $dialog.dialog("option", "width", settings.width);
      $dialog.dialog("option", "height", settings.height);
      $dialog.dialog("option", "position", {
        my: "left top",
        at: settings.position,
        of: window
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Works fine, but the height and width of some dialogs are not restored properly. When I examine their internal heights/widths with Developer Tools in Firefox it seems that they are properly stored and restored but visually some pixels are missing:

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Has anybody seen this before?